# How to pass styles to child component and use it as scoped style in Vue?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-component

I have a parent component:

```
<template>
    <ChildComponent :styles="styles" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        styles: `
            p {
                color: red
            }
        `
    })
}
</script>
```

And this is the child component:

```
<template>
    <p>Hello World</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        styles: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Now I want to use those styles provided by the parent component in child as scoped styles. Like for example:

```
<!-- ChildComponent.vue -->

<style scoped>
p {
    color: red
}
</style>
```

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: you can pass down your style as a prop afterwards just get the style object and use it on your template. `<div v-bind:style="{...styles }"></div>`
more info can be found here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you want to target the child elements with scoped styling you have to use the deep selector.

Which can be done with

```
a >>> b { color : red; }
/deep/ a b { color : red; }
a::v-deep b { color : red; }
```

Here is the full explanation: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements

Comment: `/deep/` works too https://bambielli.com/til/2018-08-19-how-to-target-child-components-with-scoped-css-in-vue/

Comment: It should be `/deep/` instead of `\deep\ ` I corrected the post

Comment: I just get `expected selector` compilation error when using `/deep/`

Comment: I never knew this `>>>` operator before. It worked! Thanks!

Comment: vue style deep selectors [doc](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#deep-selectors)

Comment: For people ending up here looking for a Vue 3 solution: The new deep selector is `:deep()`. You use it like this: `a :deep(b)`. See https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#deep-selectors

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna add the style in your child component, based on the parent component which is calling it, you can pass an attribute as a prop and use it as a class into the child component. Following your example:

Parent component:

```
<template>
    <ChildComponent styles="parent-style" />
</template>
```

Child component:

```
<template>
  <section :class="styles">
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        styles: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .parent-style {
    p {
      color: red;
    }
  }

</style>
```

Comment: This only works in a situation where you have access to the child source.  I think the far more likely scenario is you need to pass a scoped style to a child whose source you have no access to.

Comment: Adding to Jamie, another case is where you have a wrapper where every child will use the same style, so you want to apply the style once on the wrapper (parent) instead of every child, stuff like: titles, text designs, buttons, etc.

Answer (score 0):

*Please note that it does not answer **scoped** CSS.*
I am using **CSS modules**, still might help or just to improve following approach.

Send class names to child component from parent, such as:

**Parent Template**

```
<template>
  <header :class="$style.Header">

    <!-- send class names to **Child-Component** using `v-bind` through the className attribute -->
    <HeaderLogo :className="$style.Header__logo" />

</header>
</template>
```

---

**Child-Template**

```
<template>
  <div :class="className">Blah</div>
</template>
```

---

**CSS Module**

```
<style lang="scss" module>
.Header {
  white-space: nowrap;
  &__logo {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
```