# How to use vue js scoped style

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, element-ui

I am using **vue js**'s **ELEMENT UI**. And i want to override its style. I can do it with global style. But scoped style doesnt work. When i used global style it changes my all pages design. but i want to do it just for one page.

Here is my style(global style. and this is working):

```
<style>
.el-icon-close:before{
    content: "Back" !important;
}
</style>
```

but when i used scoped it doesnt work:

```
<style scoped>
.el-icon-close:before{
    content: "Back" !important;
}
</style>
```

Is there any idea about this?

Comment: You also can use the deep selector: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57704482/575468

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scoped` keyword means that this the changes to the style will apply only to the elements in the current scope. Meaning all custom made elements in the page. If you want to access elements "created" somewhere else you will have to skip the `scoped` keyword. The code that is in the scoped tag will apply only for the current page/view else it will apply for all pages/views.

All not scoped elements usually are style in the `App.vue` file. If you want to apply style of element that is not scoped just wrap it in a `div` add the class to it and style it in the scoped tag:

```
<style scoped>
.my-custom-div{
    .el-icon-close:before{
         content: "Back" !important;
    }
}
</style>
```

Atleast that is working with me.

Answer (score 0):

You must use custom class:

.custom-class{
    smthng goes here...
}

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable with  [Deep selectors](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors)

For your use case:

```
<style scoped>
.parent-div /deep/ .el-icon-close:before{
    content: "Back" !important;
}
</style>
```