# How to access Element UI library checkbox and add display: none?

Tags: css, vue.js, display, element-ui

Is there any way to add `display: none` to the styling of the Element checkbox? It has `class="el-checkbox__inner"`.

When I change the `display` to `none`, in the browser, it disappears, but I can't access this element in the code.

I tried:

```
.el-checkbox__inner { 
    display: none !important 
}
```

But it did not work.

When I use:

```
label { 
    display: none !important 
}
```

All elements disappear (as they should).

When I use:

```
label span { 
    display: none !important 
}
```

The title element disappears (as it should).

When I use:

```
label span span { 
    display: none !important 
}
```

It does not work.

I tried using `:nth-of-type()` and `:nth-child()`, but, they did not help.

Does anyone have any idea how to access the checkbox element?

---

Screenshot and code:

[image: Screenshot]

```
<el-checkbox-group v-model="itemsToBeBought">
    <el-checkbox
        v-for="(item, index) in shopItems"
        :label="item"
        :ref="item.category"
        :key="index"
    >
        <el-row>
            <el-card :body-style="{ padding: '0px' }">
                <img :src="item.image" class="image" />
                <div style="padding: 14px">
                    <span>{{ item.category }}</span>
                    <div class="bottom clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </el-card>
        </el-row>
        <el-button
            class="showDetailsButton"
            type="info"
            icon="el-icon-message"
            @click="showDetails(item)"
        >ShowDetails</el-button>
    </el-checkbox>
</el-checkbox-group>
```

Comment: Do you use scooped styling? if yes you have to use a deep selector https://stackoverflow.com/a/57704482/575468

Comment: deep selector solved the issue - thanks a lot :)