# Vue how to override css styles for element-ui

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I'm trying to override the background color on the input box from element-ui
but never worked

```
<template>
<el-input v-model="form.text" type="text" clearable></el-input>
</template

<style lang="stylus" scoped>

.el-input__inner 
    background-color #f4f4f4

</style>
```

base on the information I gathered from google

[chrome dev tool snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl2sf.png)

Comment: Try without the `scoped` attribute

Comment: as @PierreSaid , scoped does some magic to your css to scope it to the component, but you don't want that, you are wanting to style it without the scoping

Comment: Thanks guys, this has been bothering me for hours! @KeithNicholas

Comment: This changes the elementUI input globally for the entire application, not just in your component though. If that's intended I'd prefer to put those changes in a separate main.css file instead of hiding them away in a component style tag. If it's intended to change this inputbox only for this component, you'll have to leave `scoped` in and override the specificity of the original `.el-input__inner` class, for example by `!important!` or doubling (`.el-input__inner.el-input__inner`).

Comment: If you want to use scoped styling the most proper way to do this us using deep selectors: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57704482/575468

Answer (score 1):

**First option:**
Try to override

```
.el-input__inner { 
    background-color: #f4f4f4 !important;
}
```

**Second option:**
Create a seperate css file which is loaded in after the element-ui does.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open element.js in the plugins folder.
2. Add import your styles after element-plus, like this:

```js
import ElementPlus from "element-plus";
import "../element-variables.scss";
import "../assets/styles/global.scss"; // our custom styles

export default (app) => {
  app.use(ElementPlus);
};
```